# Does asking for one permission in one permissions-group give me access to all permissions in that group?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

The documentation doesn't seem to be very clear on this, [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-overview.html#permission_groups) only talks about API 23+.

I have a live app that asks for the permission `CALL_PHONE`, and now I need to release an update that asks for `READ_PHONE_STATE`, since these two belong to the group `PHONE` does it mean the user won't have to manually update the app on the Play Store and accept the permission (on API 22-)?

Answer (score 0):

Here it says that it will not ask for permissions again, when they are in the same  group (both on 22- and above). https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous